# Binding DataContext loose DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a main WPF window which will host a bunch of UserControls.
I want Every UC to have there own logic so I added a VM like this :

**UC Constructor**

```
public IfcUpdaterViewModel IfcUpdaterViewModel;
public IfcUpdaterView()
{
    IfcUpdaterViewModel = new IfcUpdaterViewModel();
    DataContext = IfcUpdaterViewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And I added a ICommand DP to bind it in the main form like this :

**UC Dependency**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UpdateCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("UpdateCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(IfcUpdaterView), new UIPropertyMetadata());

/// <summary>
/// Dependency to bind the update command
/// </summary>
public ICommand UpdateCommand
{
    get => (ICommand) GetValue(UpdateCommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(UpdateCommandProperty, value);
}
```

the binding is set with this :

**MainForm**

```
public void ToDocument()
{
    _ifcUpdater = new IfcUpdaterView();
    MainPresenter.Content = _ifcUpdater;

    _ifcUpdater.SetBinding(IfcUpdaterView.UpdateCommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(MainDataContext.UpdateIfcFile))
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    });
}
```

But with this the command binding isn't working. but if I remove the DataContext the binding working fine but I loose my VM logic.
Is there a way to combine both ?

Comment: Specify Source for your command binding

Comment: thank you so much ! I feel bad how easy it was to fix ^^'